# How to change permissions on Pantheios log files

Tags: permissions, pantheios

I am using Pantheios as my logging sweet.  The process using it is currently owned by root and the log file it creates does not create it with read permissions for all users:
-rwxr-x---, 1 root root process.log

How can I force the creation of the file to be readable to everyone?

Answer (score 0):

Use [umask function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/umask.html) to set default permissions for newly created file.